# Rounding the edges of a cylinder in matplotlib poly3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces a cylinder-like object using matplotlib:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

nphi,nz=7,20
r=1 # radius of cylinder
phi = np.linspace(0,360, nphi)/180.0*np.pi
z= np.linspace(0,1.0,nz)
print z


cols=[]
verts2 = []
for i  in range(len(phi)-1):
    cp0= r*np.cos(phi[i])
    cp1= r*np.cos(phi[i+1])
    sp0= r*np.sin(phi[i])
    sp1= r*np.sin(phi[i+1])

    for j in range(len(z)-1):
        z0=z[j]
        z1=z[j+1]
        verts=[]
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z1))
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z1))
        verts2.append(verts)
        value=np.random.rand()
        #print value
        col=plt.cm.rainbow(0.9)
        #print col
        cols.append(col)

poly3= Poly3DCollection(verts2, facecolor=cols,edgecolor = "none"  )  

poly3.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.add_collection3d(poly3)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image:[image]

However as you can see the are sharp corners in the figure. Is there anyway to make these edges rounder so that the figure looks like a proper cylinder with a circular cross-section as opposed to a hexagonal cross-section?

Comment: add more vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to
[`np.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)
controls how many values you want it to generate. Thus, `nphi` controls the
number of values in `phi`, and `nz` controls the number of values in `z`:

```
phi = np.linspace(0,360, nphi)/180.0*np.pi
z = np.linspace(0,1.0,nz)
```

- So if you increase `nphi`, then you'll get more points along the circle:

  ```
  cp0 = r*np.cos(phi[i])
  sp0 = r*np.sin(phi[i])
  ```

  For example, try changing `nphi, nz = 7,20` to `nphi, nz = 70, 2`.
- Note that there is no need for `nz` to be greater than 2 since the sides of the
  cylinder are flat in the `z` direction.
- By the way, the double for-loop can be replaced by:

  ```
  PHI, Z = np.meshgrid(phi, z)
  CP = r * np.cos(PHI)
  SP = r * np.sin(PHI)
  XYZ = np.dstack([CP, SP, Z])
  verts = np.stack(
      [XYZ[:-1, :-1], XYZ[:-1, 1:], XYZ[1:, 1:], XYZ[1:, :-1]], axis=-2).reshape(-1, 4, 3)
  ```

So, for example,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

nphi, nz = 70, 2
r = 1  # radius of cylinder
phi = np.linspace(0, 360, nphi) / 180.0 * np.pi
z = np.linspace(0, 1.0, nz)

PHI, Z = np.meshgrid(phi, z)
CP = r * np.cos(PHI)
SP = r * np.sin(PHI)
XYZ = np.dstack([CP, SP, Z])
verts = np.stack(
    [XYZ[:-1, :-1], XYZ[:-1, 1:], XYZ[1:, 1:], XYZ[1:, :-1]], axis=-2).reshape(-1, 4, 3)

cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
cols = cmap(np.random.random())
poly3 = Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolor=cols, edgecolor="none")

poly3.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.add_collection3d(poly3)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]