# How can I draw a matplotlib 3d bar but not with square columns instead with cylinder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib to draw a 3d bar plot, but the demo given only uses square columns.

[image]

Instead, I want to draw a 3D bar plot with cylindrical bars, like in this picture:

[image]

Is this natively possible to do using matplotlib?

Comment: Not sure you can do that with Matplotlib. Have you checked alternatives like Plotly and the likes?

Comment: Okay, I would give plotly a try, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sort of possible. You will have to make your own cylindrical objects and place them correctly. I have adapted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675885/rounding-the-edges-of-a-cylinder-in-matplotlib-poly3d) for your question. I am sure there is a way to modulate the cylinder properties by digging into the Poly3D class, or specifying additional vertices, but this should be a good start.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np

def cylinder(x, y, z, r=1, color='red'):
    phi = np.linspace(0, 360, 200) / 180.0 * np.pi
    z = np.linspace(0, z, z)
    PHI, Z = np.meshgrid(phi, z)
    CP = r * np.cos(PHI) + x
    SP = r * np.sin(PHI) + y
    XYZ = np.dstack([CP, SP, Z])
    verts = np.stack(
        [XYZ[:-1, :-1], XYZ[:-1, 1:], XYZ[1:, 1:], XYZ[1:, :-1]], axis=-2).reshape(-1, 4, 3)

    poly3 = Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolor=color, edgecolor="none")
    return poly3



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')


colors = (plt.cm.RdBu_r(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 25))

for x in range(1, 6):
    for y in range(1, 6):
        cyl = cylinder(x=x, y=y, z=x*y, r=0.5, color=next(colors))
        cyl.set_alpha(0.7)
        ax.add_collection3d(cyl)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0.5, 5.5)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(0.5, 5.5)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(-25, 25)
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: Could it be solid? I want it to be solid cylinder

Comment: yes, you should remove `cyl.set_alpha(0.7)` and also play around with the `edgecolor`  and `linewidth` argument to  Poly3DCollection

Comment: This code is kinda weird to me, Im confused how can I change the height of the cylinder to the number I want, my expected height is between 0 to 1 and z only receive int, and I think it wouldn't work for negetive z.

Comment: Oh! `z = np.linspace(0, z, z)` is the issue. I guess I was being a bit lazy here. You can change that to `z = np.linspace(0, z, zint)`, where `zint` has to be an integer that is proportional to `z`. `z` can then be any real number

Comment: Im sorry but I still got one question, can I possibly make the cylinder corresponding to the x and y label? Like the examples given on my question, I find your replies are all very helpful but it's still hard to make cylinder not randomly drawn in the plot

Comment: No issues. The function `cylinder` does take in the arguments `x` and `y` which you can use, i.e, if you want a cylinder placed at x=2.5, y=3.3, you can use `cyl=cylinder(x=2.5, y=3.3)`. You can also control the radius of the cylinder by the argument `r`.

Comment: Sorry, I promise this would be the last question, could the cylinder be closed? how can I draw the top face and the bottom face ? I would really appreciate it if you coulf help me solve this problem